# Is there a way to print value in variable in angular4 component from console?

Tags: html, angular, angular-components, browser-console

I save simple key in a variable in a component using angular 4, when the app closed every value will erased and i know it.

this is a simple sample :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  data : any;

  constructor() {
    this.data = "Hello";
  }

}
```

I just want to know is there a way using browser console to show value in `this.data` without `console.log()`?

Comment: What's wrong with `console.log()`?

Comment: You can't make a console log from a destroyed component.

Comment: I just want to be sure, every value saved in value in angular component can't be accessed from browser console

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Start by finding some HTML that belongs to your component in your page. Then, inspect it.

In Chrome, you will see a `$0` besides it. That's a **variable reference**.

Now, go into your console and type

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance
```

This will log you your whole component, with the variables that are in it. You can simply give it a reference

```
const myRef = ng.probe($0).componentInstance
```

Then delete your component as you want, and log it again **from the console directly**

```
console.log(myRef) // or shorthand
myRef
```